# Arcpy cannot locate rasters inside geodatabase

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, raster-calculator, nameerror

I've bunch of rasters inside a geodatabase and I'm trying to call them as inputs in a script, but I'm running into a strange problem. The script cannot find/locate these rasters, so I manually added and inspected the rasters. They appear to be valid and not corrupt. Next, I exported these rasters as TIF files and tried locating these files. Here are the results:

```
# Trying to call in rasters from my gdb
import arcpy, os

coName = "KENT_10001"

DEV = os.path.join("C:/Imagery/", str(coName) + "_Masks.gdb/", str(coName) + "_DEV")

os.path.exists(DEV)
False
os.path.isfile(DEV)
False

#Trying to call in rasters exported from gdb as TIFs
import arcpy, os

coName = "KENT_10001"

DEV_TIF = os.path.join("C:/Imagery/", str(coName) + "_DEV.tif")

os.path.isfile(DEV_TIF)
True
os.path.exists(DEV_TIF)
True
```

I don't believe the geodatabase is corrupt, because we were successful in running other models using the same inputs from the geodatabase. Additionally, I've tried executing the same test using explicit paths as well instead of using `os.path.join` and the results are still `false` for both path and file.

**Update**

`arcpy.Exists(DEV)` returns `True` value, but when I try to call this raster into raster calculator. It gives me the following error:

```
File "<string>", line 5, in rcexec NameError: name 'DEV' is not defined Failed to execute (RasterCalculator)
```

Comment: Dev<>Dev113. should give you an error. Is it a full story? Anyway you need arcpy. Exist

Comment: Well, this is the thing with geo database rasters. Calculator very often fails on them and works perfectly fine on their clone in grid, IMG or tif format

Comment: So going down the road should I consider using a simple folder structure rather than a geodatabase? Because it seems more hassle especially rolling out complicated and batch work flows.

Comment: Most definitely, at least I use this practice. In any case edit your post so it is actual thing not hectic copy paste bits from different sources. Gives bad impression

Comment: `os.path.exists` will not ***ever*** return True on any FGDB object's arcpy path. The filesystem naming is nothing like a descriptive table name.

Comment: Apologies for the sloppy copy and pasting of the code. So it appears that this is a problem with the geodatabase rasters and not with arcpy code. Are there any other recommendations? If not I will close this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much experimentation the following method and syntax worked for me:

```
import arcpy, os

coName = "KENT_10001"
wFolder = "C:/Imagery/"
coGDB = os.path.join(str(coName) + ".gdb/")

env.workspace = os.path.join(str(wFolder), str(coGDB))
print (arcpy.Exists(env.workspace))
"True"

DEV = os.path.join(str(wFolder), str(coGDB), str(coName) + "_DEV")

print (arcpy.Exists(DEV))
"True"
```

This recognizes the rasters when used with map algebra and other geoprocessing tools.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is how you are accessing your file path within your script. [Please see this link from ESRI on Relative vs. Absolute Paths](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/supplement/pathnames-explained-absolute-relative-unc-and-url.htm). Especially this piece:

> Backward slash in scripting
>
> Programming languages that have their roots in UNIX and the C
>   programming language, such as Python, treat the backslash () as the
>   escape character. For example, \n signifies a carriage return. Since
>   paths can contain backslashes, you need to prevent backslashes from
>   being used as the escape character. A common technique is to escape
>   the backslash, as follows:
>
> `thePath = "E:\\data\\telluride\\newdata.gdb\\slopes"`
>
> Another way is to
>   convert paths into Python raw strings using the r directive, as shown
>   below. This instructs Python to ignore backslashes.
>
> `thePath = r"E:\data\telluride\newdata.gdb\slopes"`

Comment: That's what I thought initially and Ive tried using ` \\ ` and r directive with no success.